# How to make/write pyi file for many nested submodules in one pyd file

Tags: python, pybind11

if I have many submodules compiled into a pyd file (pybind11 or other tools), how can I create a pyi file?

Is each submodule should have a separate pyi file?

Or just use one and the top-level module's pyi file?How does this reflect the nesting level of submodules?

Can anyone tell me best practice? I would be grateful!